# Integrating react-cookie with react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, redux

My main application is based on this old [boilerplate](https://github.com/joshuaslate/mern-starter/tree/ac6a7d4b7839a7787aee0a1979fef34f7d291497) which I have been slowly updating. Currently, all of the dependencies have been updated except for react-cookie.

I am trying to upgrade react-cookie to version 3.0.4 using this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/using-cookies-in-react-redux-and-react-router-4-f5f6079905dc) but I need some help overcoming some challenges I am facing during the transition process.

Following the tutorial, I changed index.js to

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <CookiesProvider>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </CookiesProvider>,
  document.querySelector('.wrapper'));
```

Now, my app.js file looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie'
import Routes from '../Routes'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Routes cookies={this.props.cookies} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withCookies(App)
```

Now, my biggest concern comes here. My Routes component was never meant to be a Redux container so I changed it to this to accommodate the tutorial:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import ScrollUpButton from 'react-scroll-up-button'

// Import miscellaneous routes and other requirements
import NotFoundPage from './components/pages/not-found-page'

// Import Header and footer
import HeaderTemplate from './components/template/header'
import FooterTemplate from './components/template/footer'

// Import static pages
import HomePage from './components/pages/home-page'

// Import authentication related pages
import Register from './components/auth/register'
import Login from './components/auth/login'
import Logout from './components/auth/logout'
import ForgotPassword from './components/auth/forgot_password'
import ResetPassword from './components/auth/reset_password'
import ConfirmationMessage from './components/auth/confirmation_message'
import ResendVerificationEmail from './components/auth/resend_verification_email'

// Import dashboard pages
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/dashboard'
import ChangePassword from './components/dashboard/profile/change-password'

// Import simulator pages
import Simulator from './components/simulator/index'

// Import higher order components
import RequireAuth from './components/auth/require_auth'

const BrowserRoutes = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <HeaderTemplate logo="Stress Path Simulator" />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <Route exact path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
        <Route exact path="/reset-password/:resetToken" component={ResetPassword} />
        <Route exact path="/confirmation-message"  render={() => <ConfirmationMessage message="Please click on the link we sent to your email to verify your account." /> } />
        <Route exact path="/resend-verification-email" component={ResendVerificationEmail} />
        <Route exact path="/profile/change-password" component={RequireAuth(ChangePassword)} />
        <Route exact path="/confirmation-password-changed" render={() => RequireAuth(<ConfirmationMessage message="Password has been successfully changed!" />)} />
        <Route exact path="/simulator" component={RequireAuth(Simulator)} />
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={RequireAuth(Dashboard)} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
      <FooterTemplate />
      <ScrollUpButton />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return ({
    state: state,
    cookies: ownProps.cookies
  });
}

export const Routes = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(BrowserRoutes)

export default Routes
```

I believe the problem essentially arises here. By doing so, I thought I would have been able to use the cookies from every single component like this:

```
//get this.props.cookies
const { cookies } = this.props;

//setting a cookie
cookies.set('name', 'Ross', { path: '/' });

//getting a cookie
cookies.get('name');
```

However, that doesn't seem the case and I cannot get cookies to work in any of my components especially in my actions/auth.js.
Does anyone have any suggestions? How can I efficiently use cookies in this scenario? I am assuming I can send down the cookies prop to each component that needs it but I am curious to find out what could be the best/cleanest way of using react-cookie with redux. I am fairly new to the MERN JavaScript software stack and mostly self-thought  so I am a bit confused about some concepts. For example, if in Routes I am saving cookies into the redux's store, how can I access those cookies afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing the cookies from the App/Router down, it is better to wrap only the components that will need the cookies. For example your Login component would look like this:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
   render() {
      let { cookies } = this.props;
      let useCookie = cookies.get("testCookie");
      ...
   }
}

export default withCookies(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Login));
```

Comment: What is the `null` for in the `connect()` call?

Comment: @martin36 the null is for the mapDispatchToProps function. See https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch for more details.